# Error code 134 on installing elements for polymer

Tags: node.js, npm-install, polymer-2.x

I am trying to install paper elements for polymer, but i keep getting the error code 134

Install command i tried to run: npm install --save PolymerElements/paper-checkbox

Versions:
NPM 6.9.0
Bower 1.8.8
Polymer 1.9.10

Error log: 
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'PolymerElements/paper-checkbox' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose npm-session b7d861b33e35622a
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 verbose prepareGitDep undefined: installing devDeps and running prepare script.
8 error prepareGitDep 1>
8 error prepareGitDep > @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 prepare C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-18f97110
8 error prepareGitDep > npm run generate-types
8 error prepareGitDep
8 error prepareGitDep
8 error prepareGitDep > @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 generate-types C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-18f97110
8 error prepareGitDep > gen-typescript-declarations --deleteExisting --outDir . --verify
9 error prepareGitDep 2> npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.
9 error prepareGitDep FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
9 error prepareGitDep  1: 00007FF6C37EC6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
9 error prepareGitDep  2: 00007FF6C37C7416 node::MakeCallback+4534
9 error prepareGitDep  3: 00007FF6C37C7D90 node_module_register+2032
9 error prepareGitDep  4: 00007FF6C3AE189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
9 error prepareGitDep  5: 00007FF6C3AE17CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
9 error prepareGitDep  6: 00007FF6C3CC7F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
9 error prepareGitDep  7: 00007FF6C3CBEF76 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
9 error prepareGitDep  8: 00007FF6C3CBD5CC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
9 error prepareGitDep  9: 00007FF6C3CC6317 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
9 error prepareGitDep 10: 00007FF6C3CC6396 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
9 error prepareGitDep 11: 00007FF6C3DF0637 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
9 error prepareGitDep 12: 00007FF6C3E6D826 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
9 error prepareGitDep 13: 0000036260A5C5C1
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 134
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 generate-types: `gen-typescript-declarations --deleteExisting --outDir . --verify`
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 134
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR!
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 generate-types script.
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
9 error prepareGitDep
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR!     C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-19T16_43_41_685Z-debug.log
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 134
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 prepare: `npm run generate-types`
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 134
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR!
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.1 prepare script.
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
9 error prepareGitDep
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
9 error prepareGitDep npm ERR!     C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-19T16_43_41_748Z-debug.log
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for github:PolymerElements/paper-checkbox premature close
11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 74372ms
13 verbose stack Error: premature close
13 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onclose (C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:47:67)
13 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:203:15)
13 verbose stack     at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:8)
13 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
14 verbose cwd C:\websites\polymerApp
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
16 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Robert-Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "PolymerElements/paper-checkbox"
17 verbose node v10.16.0
18 verbose npm  v6.9.0
19 error premature close
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I expected it to install correctly on my laptop, but i get the same result over there

Answer (score 0):

I have this error sometimes too its a common node bug you should set a max size of memory node is allowed to use. You can do that by setting your os environment variable NODE_OPTIONS

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=128"
```